# Foundation Responsive Toggle Dropdown Nav that is Sticky

Tags: zurb-foundation, toggle, responsive, nav, sticky

I'm new to Foundation and I'm trying to mix several components of Foundation into one nav bar just by using their classes and data attributes they've provided and demoed in their html.

I followed instructions for Responsive Toggle Dropdown at: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html

And I want to make that Sticky. See: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html#sticky-navigation , 'Creating a sticky Nav Menu with Title Bar, DropdownMenu, and Sticky!'

They left out the toggle part so I don't know if this is even feasible by using just the classes and data attributes they provide for the html.

I can get them both to work separately but not together. It seems buggy but it could be me. I'd love to hear from anyone out there who might have succeeded in doing this!

This is what I have so far. The wider window is sticky and responsive. The dropdown initially falls behind the jumbotron until you scroll up a bit.

The narrow window's responsive toggle works but the sticky does not. And initially the dropdown falls beneath the jumbotron until you widen the window a bit. The drilldown works fine.

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div data-sticky-container>
    <div class="top-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="medium" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%" data-top-anchor="1">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
      <div class="top-bar-title">Fruit Is Good</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-sticky-container>
    <nav class="top-bar" id="main-menu" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%" >
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" style="width: 300px;">
          <li class="menu-text">Fruit Is Good</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="apples.html">Apples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Citrus</a>
              <ul class="vertical menu">
                <li><a href="oranges.html">Oranges</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Limes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lemons</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <li><a href="bananas.html">Bananas</a></li>
          <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you can find the demo here: http://lucillekenney-demos.com/fruit/home.html

Comment: OK, so I figured it out. I used the class top-bar for a number of things such as responsive, nested. It seems 'sticky' requires a class of title-bar. I changed top-bar to title-bar in the nav class. The current code at http://lucillekenney-demos.com/fruit/home.html might differ slightly from the above since I've been monkeying around with it since that last post. But that final tweak is what made the difference, i.e., top-bar to title-bar in the nav class.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work. It fixed the problem of the dropdown falling beneath the callout or jumbotron. But now it's no longer sticky.